# Extract string from file bash

Tags: bash

I have this HTML page (template.html) & I want to extract the value of input `form_nonce`

```
       <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col s12 input-field">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="form_nonce" id="reset_form_nonce" value="66eef7c75d28e44817959c8eec1e0074"/>
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="" name="form_login" id="reset_form_login" class="input" value="" size="20"
                                               autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="none"
                                               tabindex="10"/>
                                        <label for="reset_form_login"><i class="icon-user icon"></i> Username or Email</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
<div class="row">
                                    <div class="col s12 input-field">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="form_nonce" id="reset_form_nonce" value="66eef7c75d28e44817959c8eec1e0074"/>
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="" name="form_login" id="reset_form_login" class="input" value="" size="20"
                                               autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="none"
                                               tabindex="10"/>
                                        <label for="reset_form_login"><i class="icon-user icon"></i> Username or Email</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

I used the following command:

```
NONCE=`grep -m 1 "form_nonce" template.html | awk -F '"' '{print $8}'`
```

But the problem is that I don't always receive the input in this format so sometimes it's 7 , 8 or 9. Is there a way to focus on the value keyword instead of assuming the order of the value?

#### Edit: There are multiple input with name="form_nonce"

Comment: may be `grep -Po 'name="form_nonce".*value="\K[^"]+'`

Comment: remove `-m 1` to continue search for more than one pattern

Comment: Best way seems to be an html parser (and there are plenty such parsers available). Why use bash to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `grep` and `sed`

```
grep -m 1 "form_nonce" template.html |sed -e 's/.*value="//'|sed -e 's/"\/>//'
```

In the first `sed` substitution everything upto `value="` is replaced and in second `sed` ending tag and quotes are replaced.